# SVG - place white background behind subtracted path

Tags: svg

I have been given an SVG file which represents a checkbox. It is a green circle with a checkmark inside. However, the path that makes the checkmark masks (?!?) the background, making it transparent. However we do not want a transparent background for this checkbox but rather we want to have a white checkmark on the green background. I tried to edit the SVG using VSCode, Sketch and Illustrator and got nowhere, I would be very grateful for help.

Here is the SVG:

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="512"
  height="512"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  viewBox="0 0 254000 254000"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512"
  xml:space="preserve"
  fill-rule="evenodd"
>
  <g>
    <path
      fill="#b0d25b"
      d="M127000 254000C56871 254000 0 197129 0 127000S56871 0 127000 0s127000 56871 127000 127000-56871 127000-127000 127000zm-17473-104654 76212-76211c2637-2638 6967-2611 9578 0l8642 8642c2611 2611 2611 6968 0 9578l-89509 89510c-1601 1601-3850 2231-5957 1869-1442-181-2833-814-3919-1899l-54525-54525c-2606-2606-2637-6941 0-9579l8642-8642c2638-2637 6941-2637 9579 0z"
      opacity="1"
      data-original="#48b02c"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you're interested in learning how to do this in something like Illustrator, you could ask a question on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/. It's pretty easy once you know the trick of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html,body{background-color:yellow;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Before</h1>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="512"
      height="512"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      viewBox="0 0 254000 254000"
      style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512"
      xml:space="preserve"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
    >
      <g>
        <path
          fill="#b0d25b"
          d="M127000 254000C56871 254000 0 197129 0 127000S56871 0 127000 0s127000 56871 127000 127000-56871 127000-127000 127000zm-17473-104654 76212-76211c2637-2638 6967-2611 9578 0l8642 8642c2611 2611 2611 6968 0 9578l-89509 89510c-1601 1601-3850 2231-5957 1869-1442-181-2833-814-3919-1899l-54525-54525c-2606-2606-2637-6941 0-9579l8642-8642c2638-2637 6941-2637 9579 0z"
          opacity="1"
          data-original="#48b02c"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <h1>After</h1>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 254000 254000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" fill-rule="evenodd" class="" >
        <g>
            <rect x="45000" y="35000" width="165000" height="170000" fill="#ffffff"/>
            <path fill="#b0d25b" d="M127000 254000C56871 254000 0 197129 0 127000S56871 0 127000 0s127000 56871 127000 127000-56871 127000-127000 127000zm-17473-104654 76212-76211c2637-2638 6967-2611 9578 0l8642 8642c2611 2611 2611 6968 0 9578l-89509 89510c-1601 1601-3850 2231-5957 1869-1442-181-2833-814-3919-1899l-54525-54525c-2606-2606-2637-6941 0-9579l8642-8642c2638-2637 6941-2637 9579 0z" opacity="1" data-original="#48b02c" class=""/>       
        </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also do this with clip-paths of course but it's more trouble around.

Work around i made a rectangle that fills the correct indicator.
Then i put the rectangle before the path (green circle), and i gave it a white background.

Here is a print screen to show the indicator with black color instead of transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your path is a **compound path** – it contains multiple path descriptions concatenated.
You can detect compound paths by checking the `d` attribute.
If it contains multiple `M` or `m` occurrences – it's a compound path.

Compound paths are commonly used to get cut-out shapes like the letter "o" within a single `d` path data attribute.

Dissecting your path comes down to something like this

#### Outer shape (circle)

```
 M 127000 254000
 C 56871 254000 0 197129 0 127000
 S 56871 0 127000 0
 s 127000 56871 127000 127000 
 s -56871 127000 -127000 127000
 z
```

#### Inner subtracted shape (check mark)

```
 m -17473-104654 76212-76211
 c 2637-2638 6967-2611 9578 0
 l 8642 8642
 c 2611 2611 2611 6968 0 9578
 l -89509 89510
 c -1601 1601-3850 2231 -5957 1869 
 c -1442 -181-2833 -814 -3919 -1899
 l -54525-54525
 c -2606-2606-2637-6941 0-9579
 l 8642-8642
 c 2638-2637 6941-2637 9579 0z
```

So you can decompose this path data to two seperate paths.
The subpath (checkmark) uses **relative command coordinates** indicated by the lowercase `m` command – so we first need to convert it to absolute.

You can do this with [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).
BTW. you can easily scale down your path by a factor of 1000.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 254 254">

<!-- outer shape -->
    <path
      fill="#b0d25b"
      d="M 127 254
      C 57 254 0 197 0 127
      C 0 57 57 0 127 0
      C 197 0 254 57 254 127
      C 254 197 197 254 127 254
      Z"
    />

<!-- inner shape -->
    <path
      fill="red"
      d="M 110 149L 186 73
      C 188 70 193 71 195 73
      L 204 82
      C 207 84 207 89 204 91
      L 114 181
      C 113 182 111 183 108 183
      C 107 183 106 182 105 181
      L 50 126
      C 47 124 47 119 50 117
      L 59 108
      C 61 105 66 105 68 108
      Z"
    />
</svg>
```

In **Inkscape** (free and open source - "no brainer" to include it to your tool belt) you can apply the the path/break apart operation to decompose compound paths.